# google-api-java-client setup for Android

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

I have never used Maven before.
I am following [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup) to setup google-api-client-java for Android.

I have also checked out the sample applications and trying to build calendar-android-sample but getting some Maven related errors.

Are there any other steps to integrate google api's ?

I have these errors -

1. The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Salil.m2\repository\com\google\apis-samples\shared-sample-calendar\v2-1.1.0\shared-sample-calendar-v2-1.1.0.jar'
2. Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Salil.m2\repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
3. Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Salil.m2\repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Comment: have you installed maven plugin for your eclipse? if that's eclipse your're working with.

Comment: m2e - maven integration for eclipse is installed , do I need to install anything else.

Comment: If you never used maven, stay away from it !! It's horror.

Comment: @koma I had to use maven to build the sample apps provided with google-api-java-client

Answer (score 2):

I think is more simple to just add the dependencies jars into your lib folder(from your project) and then add the lib folder to your dependencies path(you do this using your IDE).

Comment: I am using eclipse. I have added the .jar files to the project using Project Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Jars. Any thing to add to the pom.xml or maven specific ?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I just made the steps described above.. I think it's enough what you did, if you are copying a sample project in your project do you have any errors related to the library?

Comment: Solved error no 1 by renaming shared-sample-calendar-v2-1.1.0.jar.lastupdated in " C:\Users\Salil\.m2\repository\com\google\apis-samples\shared-sample-calendar\v2-1.1.0" to shared-sample-calendar-v2-1.1.0.jar. Still have error no 2.

Comment: Doing a clean build solved the errors , but now there are errors related to the library. There are about 50 errors : The import com.google.api.services cannot be resolved.

Comment: did you Copy then Paste the jars into your project's lib directory? And after that did you linked that directory to your project from eclipse? if you did that, you just have to copy the sample code in your project and do a clean build and it should work.. that worked for me and for others as well ..

Comment: I was able to build it , followed the instructions from - http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default . Imported the project into eclipse , but did not check the "Copy files into workspace" option ".